# Insert object at index of vector c++

Tags: c++, vector

I need to insert an object to existing vector of objects. I know that i need to use iterator to do it but i dont know how it exactly works.

I have alphabetically sorted vector and i need to insert new object by its name in exact index that i got after some search . So i have this.

```
vector<Person>people;


int index =54;
Person temp;

people.push_back(temp);//insert at end of vector
people.insert(index, temp);//doesnt work for int
```

Can anyone help me how to use iterator properly to insert my object to 54th index of vector and move all following object by one index ?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: how big is your people vector? if size is less than 54, you should insert it to end.

Comment: possible thousand objects stored in vector

Comment: consider using a `std::set` or a `std::map`; they are designed so that it is fast to search and insert, compared to a `vector`.

Comment: Hey I just wanted a quick clarification, if there's already an object at the index then will that object's index increase after the insertion is done?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The straight forward answer is you need an iterator. The iterator for std::vector supports random access, which means you can add or subtract an integer value to or from an iterator.

```
people.insert(people.begin() + index, temp);
```

The better answer is don't use an index, use an iterator. What is your loop? You should be able to refactor the loop to use an iterator instead of an index.

Comment: I'm an avid supporter of iterators in most cases.

Answer (score 3):

> I have alphabetically sorted vector and i need to insert new object by its name in exact index that i got after some search.

If the `vector` is sorted alphabetically, then the proper way of inserting an item in the correct position while maintaining the sort order is using the [`upper_bound`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/upper_bound/) function:

```
people.insert(upper_bound(people.begin(), people.end(), temp), temp);
```

The function searches the sorted range, and returns the position of the first element that is greater than `temp`.

[Here is a demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/deAY0C)

Comment: Does it search with linear complexity ? That would be very slow. For example i have 10000 objects in vector and i need to save something to very last position, doest it search index by index until it reaches end of vector ? I need something like binary search for searching right position.

Comment: @TomášPastorek "Does it search with linear complexity?" Of course not! `find` is the one that searches linearly, while both `upper_bound` and `lower_bound` run a binary search. Check out the complexity section of the linked documentation for information on the timing of the algorithm employed by `upper_bound`.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
    vector<Person>::iterator iter = people.begin() + index;
    people.insert(iter, temp);
```

---

Reference:

- [std::vector::insert()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/insert/)
- [RandomAccessIterator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/RandomAccessIterator/)